# FileMaker calculated filtered list

Tags: filemaker

I am currently getting a list of related field like so

```
List ( join_table::id_b;)'
```

and what i would like to do is filter that list by a second field in the same related table pseudo code as follows

```
List ( join_table::id_b;jointable:other="foo")
```

not really sure how to filter it down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `List()` function will return a list of (non-empty) values from **all** related records.

To get a list filtered by a second field, you could do any one of the following:

1. Define a calculation field in the join table = `If ( other = "foo" ; id_b )` and use this field in your `List()` function call instead of the `id_b` field;
2. Construct a relationship filtered by the `other` field;
3. Use the `ExecuteSQL()` function instead of `List()`;
4. Write your own recursive custom function (requires the Advanced version to install).

Comment: I found that using ExecuteSQL was easiest for me